# Transpositions Generate the Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, symmetric-groups

Feel free to close or migrate this question if you feel that it doesn't belong on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

My abstract algebra professor claims that there is a sign at a mathematics library in Budapest that says something like, "Please do not reshelve the books. Transpositions generate the symmetric group." The implication here is that by reshelving the books themselves and inadvertently swapping the order of two books, the patrons can rearrange the whole library! However, neither my professor nor a quick Google search were able to produce any evidence of the sign. My question is, can you? Thank you!

Comment: I believe that the question is about the existence of a sign in a library, not about the claim that transpositions generate the symmetric group. I wasn't able to find another reference on this site with a quick search. Is this really a question about mathematics? Perhaps not. But "duplicate question" seems like the wrong reason for closing.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Searching "library theorem" on Google and Mathematics Stack Exchange doesn't appear to return any relevant results.

Comment: @JohnHughes I apologize for the ambiguity. You are correct. The claim asserts that there is a sign in a library with particular properties, not that transpositions generate the symmetric group. I have edited the question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood the question. It is reopened.

Comment: If someone *can* answer in the affirmative, it would be a service to all of us if you could include a photo in your answer. :)

Comment: Have you tried emailing e.g. mathlib@cs.elte.hu (Mathematical Library of Eötvös Loránd University, https://web.cs.elte.hu/library/)? Admittedly, "a mathematics library in Budapest" could mean other places, but they would be my first guess, and if they are not, they might know who is.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you for the reference! I tried emailing them, but it bounced. I will try some other mathematics libraries in Budapest, but in the meantime, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: https://www.math.elte.hu/en/institute/contact-info/ is hopefully more up to date. There is no e-mail address for the library in particular, but the institute people might know or refer further.